How to get rid of C6387 warning on call to fwrite function?
In Visual Studio 2022, I am getting the following warning when I call fwrite.
Warning image C6387
It says: C6387:'fout' could be '0': this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'fwrite'.
Here is how I initialize the variables I pass to fwrite.
float* fin;
FILE* fpOut = fopen("test.pcm", "wb");
int out_len = 100;
fout = malloc(256 * sizeof(float));

//... some code...

fwrite(fout, sizeof(float), out_len, fpOut); //Visual Studio underlines this full line and display the above Warning.

Am I using fwrite in an unsafe manner? Any idea how to address this warning?
Thanks in advance.
I tried to cast the type of my memory allocation of fOut, but the warning still remains.
fout = (float*)malloc(256 * sizeof(float));

I also tried to pass to fwrite (float*)fout and then (void*)fout but no success.
So, I am thinking the warning has to do with the value of fout and not its type.
I also tried using calloc instead of malloc to initialize fout, but not success either.

Please don't post images of text. If you get build errors or warnings, then copy-paste the full and complete output as text into your question.

With the above said, it seems the compiler think you don't have enough null-pointer handling to check if the malloc call failed or not. Or it can't trace the usage of fout between the malloc call and the fwrite call. The warning tells you that the compiler thinks that fout might be a null pointer.

Besides that, in C you should not cast the result of malloc. Or any function returning a void *.

Thanks, that's an interesting on why not to cast the result of malloc. Indeed, I just had to take care of the case when fout is a null pointer, then the warning disappears.

Sorry for the post, ChatGPT already helped me to solve this one.
The solution is to take care of the situation when fout is not initialized properly.
if (fout == NULL)
{
     fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation failed for fout\n");
     return 1;
}


BTW, does your code check if fpOut is NULL? The probability of fpOut ending up NULL is far greater than the probability of malloc not being able to allocate space for a few floats.
